# Why does the overridden name property log as undefined

Tags: typescript

In the following code why does the overridden name property log as undefined?

log::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
undefinedrunCustomCode
Machines.tsx:19 undefined
Machines.tsx:34 undefinedrunCustomCode
Machines.tsx:19 undefined
Machines.tsx:40 undefinedrunCustomCode
Machines.tsx:19 undefined
```

code::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;

```
interface iMachine {
  name: string
  runCustomCode(): void
  showMachineName(): void
}

abstract class AbstractBase {
  abstract name: string

  abstract runCustomCode(): void

  constructor() {
    this.runCustomCode()
    this.showMachineName()
  }

  showMachineName = () => {
    console.log(this.name)
  }


}

class To extends AbstractBase implements iMachine {
  name: string = 'the to'
  runCustomCode() {
    console.log(this.name + 'runCustomCode')
  }
}
class TV extends AbstractBase implements iMachine {
  name: string = 'the TV'
  runCustomCode() {
    console.log(this.name + 'runCustomCode')
  }
}
class Radio extends AbstractBase implements iMachine {
  name: string = 'the Radio'
  runCustomCode() {
    console.log(this.name + 'runCustomCode')
  }
}





const T = new To()
const TVa = new TV()
const Radioa = new Radio()

console.log([To, TVa, Radioa])
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason of undefined instead of `this.name` is order of executing methods. Constructor of `AbstractBase` is called before you assign `name` attribute (name is assigning in `To` constructor).

----- Edited ----

For sure you have to move `this.runCustomCode(); this.showMachineName()` from AbstractBase constructor. You can create protected method e.g. protected afterInit and call it into To constructor after super()

Check playground section. In JS code `afterInit` is called after `this.name = '...'`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20iMachine%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%0A%20%20runCustomCode()%3A%20void%0A%20%20showMachineName()%3A%20void%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20AbstractBase%20%7B%0A%20%20abstract%20name%3A%20string%0A%0A%20%20abstract%20runCustomCode()%3A%20void%0A%0A%0A%20%20showMachineName%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.name)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20afterInit()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.runCustomCode()%0A%20%20%20%20%20this.showMachineName()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20To%20extends%20AbstractBase%20implements%20iMachine%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'the%20to'%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.afterInit()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20runCustomCode()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.name%20%2B%20'runCustomCode')%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20TV%20extends%20AbstractBase%20implements%20iMachine%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'the%20TV'%0A%20%20runCustomCode()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.name%20%2B%20'runCustomCode')%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Radio%20extends%20AbstractBase%20implements%20iMachine%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'the%20Radio'%0A%20%20runCustomCode()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.name%20%2B%20'runCustomCode')%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks. May i ask how you would fix that without adding a constructor to each class?

Comment: @Hello-World Is this solution fine to you?